# How to lock with Android a counter from a Firebase database till the item from a ListView disappears?

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created a list in which i display some products. The list can be shared with multiple users. The list has a field named `numberOfProducts`. Every time a product is added to the list, the counter is increased by one. Every time a product is deleted, the counter is decreased by one. To display the products from the list, i use a `ListView` and a `FirebaseListAdapter`. If the list is displayed an 2 different devices, when a user is deleting a product, that item disappears from the `ListView` of his device and the counter is decreased by one.

My problem is, that on the second device, that item disappears after a half of second. In this short time, if the second user tries to delete the same product, the counter is decreased again. So in stead of having removed one item, the counter is decreased by two.

My question is, how can i lock the `numberOfProducts` counter, not to be written till the item from the second device disappears?

The code for decreasing the counter is this:

```
void decreaseCounter(String listKey) {
    final DatabaseReference ref = listsDatabaseReference.child(listKey).child("numberOfProducts");
    ref.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(final MutableData currentData) {
            if (currentData.getValue() == null) {
                currentData.setValue(0);
            } else {
                int numberOfProducts = currentData.getValue();
                int decreasedNumberOfProducts = numberOfProducts - 1;
                currentData.setValue(decreasedNumberOfProducts);
            }
            return Transaction.success(currentData);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean committed, DataSnapshot currentData) {
            if (databaseError != null) {
                System.out.println("Firebase counter increment failed!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Firebase counter increment succeeded!");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is the delete operation taking place? Since that's the source of the bug, you probably need to include it to get any real help here. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). One thought would be to use Functions to do the decrement, instead of relying on the clients. But you probably just want your delete in a transaction, too. Alternately, you might just want to check that the current counter value matches what you have locally and abort the change if it has been altered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Firebase Transactions